# How can a string of HTTP request headers to display line by line?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and python. Currently i am using python script to get the HTTP header, but the output is not really neat. Is there any way i am able to split each of the contents to display one line each? Thank you in advance.

```
import json
import requests

something = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
test1 = something.headers
result = json.dumps(dict(test1))
print (result)
```

```
{"Date": "Wed, 00 Jun 2021 00:00:00 GMT", "Expires": "-1", "Cache-Control": "private, max-age=0", "Content-Type": "text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1", "P3P": "CP=\"This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info.\"", "Content-Encoding": "gzip", "Server": "gws", "Content-Length": "5804", "X-XSS-Protection": "0", "X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN",}
```

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."
Date: Wed, 09 Jun 2021 00:00:00 GMT
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Expires: Wed, 00 Jun 2021 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: private
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty print is your friend. This module is very useful for printing json, dictionaries, lists, etc...

```py
from pprint import pprint

pprint(result)
```

Edit:

Just realized you can make your code a lot shorter, as you don't need to make a json out of the headers:

```py
import requests
from pprint import pprint

something = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
test1 = something.headers

pprint(test1)
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to python.

json.dumps() has functionality that allows you to do that. As a second parameter inside your function, add 'indent = 2', it should make it prettier and separate the content by line.

```
json.dumps(dict(test1),indent=2)
```